# How do I make this makefile from 1996 work?

Tags: c, windows, macos, makefile, compiler-errors

This is the make file for an old GSM standard from 1996. I need to make it work on either on my MacBook running OSX 10.11.6 or on a University Computer which is Windows 7. The windows does not have nmake installed which after googling the problem seemed like a solution.

Is there maybe a way around using the makefile?

Also, changing CDIR and UTILSDIR to the full path is not enough on my Mac.

```
make -f makefile.mak
```

still returns

```
TCC -A -I/Users/Henrik/Desktop/GSMHR2/DISK/c -Fc -ml -c /Users/Henrik/Desktop/GSMHR2/DISK/c/gsm_hr.c
make: TCC: No such file or directory
make: *** [gsm_hr.obj] Error 1
```

I assume a similar problem will occur with TCDIR
This is the full makefile.mak content:

```
#
#   makefile for GSM Half-Rate Speech Codec
#   Version 5.0.0
#   November 8, 1996
#
.SUFFIXES: .out .obj .c .e .r .f .y .l .s .p .os
CC=TCC
CDIR=..\c
UTILSDIR=..\utils

TCDIR=c:/turboc/lib
CAlsoDef=-A -I$(CDIR) -Fc -ml
CDefault=$(CAlsoDef)
CDefaultExec=$(CAlsoDef)

# installation
install: gsm_hr reid swapbin tosnwild topcwild

# EXACT files
globdefs.obj:  $(CDIR)/globdefs.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
mathdp31.obj:  $(CDIR)/mathdp31.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
mathhalf.obj:  $(CDIR)/mathhalf.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?

# 
# speech coder: analysis and synthesis
#  object files
#
dtx.obj:  $(CDIR)/dtx.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
err_conc.obj:  $(CDIR)/err_conc.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
homing.obj:  $(CDIR)/homing.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
sp_dec.obj:  $(CDIR)/sp_dec.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
sp_enc.obj:  $(CDIR)/sp_enc.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
sp_rom.obj:  $(CDIR)/sp_rom.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
sp_sfrm.obj:  $(CDIR)/sp_sfrm.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
sp_frm.obj:  $(CDIR)/sp_frm.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
vad.obj:  $(CDIR)/vad.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?

# Host files
host.obj:  $(CDIR)/host.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?

# main program
gsm_hr.obj: $(CDIR)/gsm_hr.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?

# utility programs
reid.obj:  $(UTILSDIR)/reid.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
swapbin.obj:  $(UTILSDIR)/swapbin.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
topcwild.obj:  $(UTILSDIR)/topcwild.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?
tosnwild.obj:  $(UTILSDIR)/tosnwild.c
    $(CC) $(CDefault) -c $?

# ***********************  symbols ******************************************

EXACT3 = globdefs.obj mathdp31.obj mathhalf.obj 

SPEECH = sp_dec.obj sp_enc.obj sp_frm.obj sp_rom.obj sp_sfrm.obj

GSM_HR = $(EXACT3) $(SPEECH) dtx.obj err_conc.obj host.obj homing.obj vad.obj


#***********************  executables  **************************************

# main program
gsm_hr: gsm_hr.obj $(GSM_HR)  
    $(CC) $(CDefaultExec) -egsm_hr.exe @gsm_hr.rsp 

# utility programs
reid: reid.obj
    $(CC) $(CDefaultExec) -ereid.exe  reid.obj
swapbin: swapbin.obj
    $(CC) $(CDefaultExec) -eswapbin.exe  swapbin.obj
tosnwild: tosnwild.obj
    $(CC) $(CDefaultExec) -etosnwild.exe  tosnwild.obj
topcwild: topcwild.obj
    $(CC) $(CDefaultExec) -etopcwild.exe  topcwild.obj
```

Full files can be found here https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=281

Comment: We are no debugging/porting service.

Comment: This Makefile was written to work with Turbo C. Try finding a copy of it and see where it goes.

Comment: You'd probably be better off starting with the file named "MAKEFILE" rather than the one named "MAKEFILE.MAK", at least for building on OS X.

Comment: Do you actually have `turbo C`?   If so, is it installed at the `c/turbo/lib` directory?   If you do not have turbo C, then you will need to modify the makefile.mak to use some modern `make` utility via the syntax that that modern `make` utility expects.

Comment: following the link you gave to the source files, I only found an executable of the program that displayed a 'live' menu.   Perhaps you could modify that link to go to the actual source files

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove `CC=TCC`. This is a reference to an ancient DOS C compiler (Turbo C).
2. Replace the backslashes in `CDIR` and `UTILSDIR` with forward slashes. Backslashes in paths are a MS-DOS-ism.
3. Replace `CAlsoDef=-A -I$(CDIR) -Fc -ml` with `CAlsoDef=-I$(CDIR)`. The other options are specific to TCC.
4. Hope that the source code doesn't need too many changes. Good luck.